# Android PreferenceActivity wiered behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application Preference Setting Activity is not showing correctly sometimes. It goes black.

My Original Preference Activity

[image]

But sometimes it goes black and shows as below screenshot

[image]

no check boxes and list preference are visible.

When it goes black and I scroll It looks very poor

[image]

The Declaration in Manifest file

```
          <activity
        android:name="com.test.wallpaper.PreferenceSettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have need to set Background for parent layout in this xml page.

Use setbackground for parent layout in xml.

Comment: It is not working. This is a PreferenceActivity and I am using addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) for this view. As per your suggestion I created a layout and set background but the same problem occurs randomly.